# Why does VM software change the volume ID of virtual hard disks when cloning?

Tags: virtual-machines

I can understand why you wouldn't want a MAC address conflict, but why does the volume ID of the hard disk matter? What can go wrong?

Comment: maybe you want to mount the cloned hard disk on the original VM later.

Comment: Yeah. Assuming they will never meet again ever is like a little not smart. There can be various scenarios where you move hd images around and then - ah - yeah, they better have different id's.